# Is there any functional reason for the wheel joints to be continuous instead of fixed?

Tags: ros, rviz, create-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The create.urdf.xacro file labels the wheel joints as continuous:

```
<joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
```

but then turtlebot_node.py publishes a transform for that joint that never changes.

It seems like that is just adding overhead.

Is there any reason not to just set the wheels to fixed like this:

```
<joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="fixed">
```

It appears to work from testing, but I am afraid that it might come back to bite me later in something like gmapping or some other future use of my robot that I haven't tested yet.

**Can anyone tell me if a fixed wheel joint will have any negative repercussions, other than an inability to "animate" it in RVIZ?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186560/is-there-any-functional-reason-for-the-wheel-joints-to-be-continuous-instead-of-fixed?/) by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK the main reason is integration with gazebo, as the wheels have to "really" rotate in simulation for dynamics engine based wheeled locomotion to work. If you are others otherwise not interested in spinning wheels, you can safely set them to "fixed".

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on 2014-07-16**:
That is good to know. I will note that in my code in case I decide to attempt to run my robot in gazebo some day.